# Number of unique combinations of painting N squares with M paint blocks each of length K squares

Tags: recursion, combinatorics

I came across a programming challenge recently and I'm wondering if there's a closed-form solution to this.

There is a strip with squares of unit length each. The strip's total length is N (i.e. there are N squares). You have M paint blocks each of which has a length of K units. You can paint over the squares with these paint blocks however many times you want. How many unique combinations can you make?

Ex. N = 3, M = 2, K = 2 gives 6 unique combinations (000 , 111, 011, 100, 001, 110)

I currently have a brute-force algorithm to solve this, but I'm sure there has to be a more elegant solution, possibly a closed-form equation that I'm missing.

I am not a student and this is not a homework question. I just do these for fun.

Thanks for your help@